# why can't I scroll down in IE on my site

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll

In IE 8 I can't scroll down to the bottom of my page on my site
the base URL has a wordpress install but the subsiduary urls are all hand coded (not WP)
Take a basic url like http://isseomarketing.com/privacy-policy-terms-of-use/
Nothing fancy here just header, footer and a bunch of disclaimer text

The two stylesheets for the above page are:
http://isseomarketing.com/css/seo.css
http://isseomarketing.com/css/rdc.css

I just can't figure it out - works fine in other browsers and my friend said he could view the site fine in ie 6,7 and 8 but I don't think it is a problem with my computer/mouse etc because with the same IE install I am able to scroll to the bottom of other sites.

Ugggh. Would someone be so kind as to have a look or if you've encountered this issue before - make a suggestion?

Kind regards, Leah D.

Comment: What exactly does "can't scroll down" mean? There's no scroll bar? It does nothing? You scroll down and it immediately jumps back up? The browser crashes?

Comment: Thanks Eric - on my IE 8 that is correct, I see no scrollbar at all...I'm not able to scroll down on mine but it doesn't crash or jump back up...do you have an idea as to what might be going on - I don't believe I am missing any closing divs etc that would drastically mess up the site...
thanks much

Answer (score 8):

OK I'm answering my own question. The reason IE would not scroll is because I had this in the css :

```
html   {
height:100%; 
margin-bottom:0px; 
overflow-y:scroll; 
overflow-x:hidden; 
}
```

The solution was to remove height:100%;

That's it - should work like a charm now (does in IE8 anyway)
Leah

Comment: overflow-x:hidden; is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had not declared height:100% on anything. The scroll bar was present but simply would NOT scroll all the way down in IE8 *only*.

I had to actually **add** `height:100%` to my `html` and `body` tags.

```
html#ie8,
html#ie8 body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I don't really know *why* it happened, but it's fixed in IE8 now!

P.S. I'm using a handy bit of markup to get ID's IN IE for specific targeting like I've shown in my solution. I got it out of the Wordpress default 2012 theme. I use it almost all the time if I have to care about IE compatibility on any level. It saves having to make extra calls for IE specific stylesheets, and it's just more convinient to be able to add a quick fix in the context of your normal CSS for any given elemnet.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" lang="en">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" lang="en">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" lang="en">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<html id="ie9" lang="en">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8) | !(IE 9)  ]><!-->
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This just fixed it for me in IE11!